# Google Earth Engine - image gap filling in imagecollection

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

i need to combine MODIS Terra and Aqua collection in a new collection in order to get the max NDSI value by day.

The problem is that, for some years, the dataset has some gaps and the join function keeps just the common images on the two dataset.

For example in 2003 the Terra dataset has 358 images while the Aqua ones has 365, the combined dataset results with just 358 images.

I would like the combine function keeps the Aqua images values when the Terra ones are not available in order to have 365 images at the end.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

here is the GEE link to the code
https://code.earthengine.google.com/b71873bff48fe5f3de883763f25c4938

here is the code

```
var MOD = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD10A1")
var MYD = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MYD10A1")



var ROI = geometry


// MONITORING DATE
var currdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2004,1,1)
var firstdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2003,1,1)



Map.centerObject(ROI,5);

var clip = function(img) {return img.clip(ROI);}   

var MOD  = MOD.filterDate(firstdate, currdate)
              .map(clip)
var MYD  = MYD.filterDate(firstdate, currdate)
              .map(clip)
print(MOD,'MOD')
print(MYD,'MYD')



// Combine collections (MOD & MYD)
var Filter = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});

var simpleJoin = ee.Join.inner();
var innerJoin = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoin.apply(MOD, MYD, Filter))

var comb = innerJoin.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary'));
})
print(comb,'comb');


// calculate maximum value from the two MODIS images
var max = function(img) {
  var br = img.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover').max(img.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover_1'))
     return br.rename('NDSI')
            .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start', 'system:time_end']);
}


var NDSImax = comb.map(max)

print(NDSImax,'NDSImax')
// Map.addLayer(NDSImax.first().clip(ROI).select('NDSI'),{min: -9,max: 100,palette: ['red', 'white', 'blue']}, 'NDSImax')
```